# Another way to prevent/show no result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rdbms

If tab1 AND tab2 return NO results only then do I want 
the final select 0,0... to be returned.

```
select tab1.openedcnt, tab2.closedcnt, 'ModuleA' AS Module
from
(select count(*) openedcnt,'constant1' const
WHERE 1=1) tab1
   cross join
(select count(*) closedcnt,'constant2' const
WHERE 1=2 )tab2-- simulating no result set returned
union
select 0,0,'ModuleA'
```

Results in...

```
openedcnt   closedcnt   Module
0   0   ModuleA
1   0   ModuleA
```

I can't get rid of cross join.
The where statements are only for purposes of this example.

For example...if tab1 returns result and tab2 does not 
then I'm looking to get results of...

```
openedcnt   closedcnt   Module
1   0   ModuleA
```

If tab1 AND tab2 do not return results then I'm looking to get results of...

```
openedcnt   closedcnt   Module
0   0   ModuleA
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I think you can do this rather directly using `union all` and `not exists`.  Here is the idea:

```
with tab1 as (
      select count(*) openedcnt, 'constant1' const
      where 1=1
     ),
     tab2 as (
      select count(*) closedcnt, 'constant2' const
      where 1=2
     )
select tab1.*
from tab1
union all
select tab2.*
from tab2
union all
select 0, 0, 'ModuleA'
where not exists (select 1 from tab1) and not exists (select 1 from tab2);
```

Note the use of the CTEs to make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: Sorry...I incorrectly tagged sql server 2008 r2 when I only have sql server 2008. I got "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near ','."  The comma previous to tab2.